# Running snappyData with spark 2.2

Tags: snappydata

Is there a way to run snappyData in smart-connector mode with spark 2.2 ? The documentation says only version 2.1 is supported.

I tried using snappyData-1.0.1 with spark 2.2 but it does not work.

Comment: SnappyData can be used as a JDBC source with any Spark version

Comment: But we will not be able to make a SnappySession right ? Creating one gives me an error with spark 2.2 and works with spark 2.1 .

Comment: you can also use the Spark Data source API using the JDBC driver to snappydata.  Here is an [example](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/exercises/spark-exercise-dataframe-jdbc-postgresql.html)